# How to allow fallback prop in React error boundary with Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-error-boundary

I have an error boundary on top of my app. It works, and I can pass it a custom component as a fallback. However, Typescript claims that:

> Property 'fallback' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>' (errorboundary.js)

and that

> No overload matches this call. (index.tsx)

```js
import { Component } from "react";

export class ErrorBoundary extends Component {
  state = { error: null };

  static getDerivedStateFromError(error) {
    return { error };
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.error) {
      return this.props.fallback;
    }
    return this.props.children;
  }
}
```

How to fix this?

Please note I'm not using the react-error-boundary library. The native error boundary class should do the work.

EDIT: complete working code:

```js
interface Props {
  fallback: React.ReactNode;
}

export class ErrorBoundary extends Component<Props> {
  state = { error: null };

  static defaultProps: Props = {
    fallback: [],
  };

  static getDerivedStateFromError(error) {
    return { error };
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.error) {
      return this.props.fallback;
    }
    return this.props.children;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should extend `Component` passing the type definition of your props, like this:

```js
interface ErrorBoundaryProps {
  fallback: JSX.Element; // if fallback is a JSX.Element
}

interface ErrorBoundaryState {
  error: boolean | null;
}

export class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component<ErrorBoundaryProps, ErrorBoundaryState> { ... }
```

Comment: Yes, and also declare the static defaultProps in the class. I've edited the question with the full working code.